Concat in Power Automate
How do you make a concat where it would be IAR-year of audit date - F if audit date is April 1 - September 30 plus 01 for the sequencing and IAR-year of audit date -S if audit date is October 1 - March 31 plus 01 for the sequencing. Example: IAR-2024F-01.
It would not affect the condition of Do until(Looping), where looping would end if the Status is equal to APPROVED.

Sorry but ... huh?  Can you show an example of inputs and expected outputs?

first check if the audit date falls in April 1 - September 30 range or October 1 - March 31 range
pseudo:
IF month(audit_date) >= 4 AND month(audit_date) <= 9
    CONCATENATED_STRING = "IAR-" & year(audit_date) & "F-01"
ELSE
    CONCATENATED_STRING = "IAR-" & year(audit_date) & "S-01"

few reference expressions that you can use to

get year: formatDateTime(variables('audit_date'), 'yyyy')
get month: int(formatDateTime(variables('audit_date'), 'MM'))

final expression to compose the output should look like
concat('IAR-', formatDateTime(variables('audit_date'), 'yyyy'), 
       if(and(greaterOrEquals(int(formatDateTime(variables('audit_date'), 'MM')), 4), 
              lessOrEquals(int(formatDateTime(variables('audit_date'), 'MM')), 9)), 
          'F', 
          'S'), 
       '-01')


Can you try those steps:-
1)AuditYear variable:-
formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/AuditDate'], 'yyyy')

2)AuditMonth variable :-
formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/AuditDate'], 'MM')

3)Condition Logic: Use a Condition to check the month:
If AuditMonth is between 04 and 09 then Set AuditPeriod to F.
If AuditMonth is 01, 02, 03, 10, 11, 12 then Set AuditPeriod to S.
4)Compose action for the concatenation:
concat('IAR-', variables('AuditYear'), variables('AuditPeriod'), '-01')


Do Until Loop, loop runs until the Status is equal to APPROVED

